# How can I dynamically unbox a value in F#?

Tags: f#

I am trying to achieve the automatic/dynamic cast in the fourth line below:

```
let a = 1 // type: int
let b = box a // type: obj
b.GetType() // System.Int32, so it is perfectly aware what it is!
let c = unbox b  // fails....
```

The following would would work in the final line above BUT would require me to know and explicitly mark ahead-of-time the primitive/value type that I am working with (which I am trying to avoid):

```
let c1:int = unbox b
let c2 = b :?> int
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  Whilst this is possible, it often ends up being very awkward and you lose mush of the safety of the F# type system.

Comment: There's a distinction between what the compiler knows and what the runtime knows. The runtime knows what type an `obj` is, just ask it by calling `GetType` like you did above. However, the compiler only knows it's an `obj` which could be a `int`, `string` and so on. In your example one could argue that the F# compiler could infer from looking at the expression tree that `b` is really an `int` but that only works for trivial cases and then why box at all?

Answer (score 3):

While `b` knows *at run-time* what it is, the *compiler* doesn't, because it's an `obj`.

If *you* know, at compile time, what it is, you can unbox it like this:

```
let a = 1 
let b = box a 
b.GetType()
let c = unbox<int> b
```

`c` is now an `int`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid the direct usage of <int> at compile time because I envisage a scenario where it could be other value types. Is there not a way to dynamically extract the type from 'b' at run-time and use that in the casting/unboxing?

Comment: @Sam - If you don't know what the expected type is then you can't cast it. If you don't need to know the exact type then you don't need to do anthing, since as you can see, the type is maintained at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`unbox` only does anything if the type can be explicitly or implicitly determined at compile time.  Here it will implicitly (and wrongly) try to convert the `object` to a `string`, as that's how it is used in the subsequent line.

```
let a = 1 
let b = box a 
b.GetType()
let c = unbox b
printf "%s" c
```

This of course gives a runtime error because it is *not* a string.

There's no way to have `unbox` convert to "what it actually is under the hood", as there's no definite way of determining this at compile time.  There may be another way to do what you're trying to do though, if you can provide more details.

If you're wanting to, say create a generic unboxed list from boxed objects, you can do something like this:

```
let addToList (l: 'a list) (o: obj) = // type annotations optional
  let o' = unbox o  // unboxes to generic type 'a
  o'::l

let l = [1;2;3]
let b = box 4
let l' = addToList l b // l' is list<int>, not list<obj>

let l2 = [1.;2.;3.]
let b2 = box 4.
let l2' = addToList l2 b2 // l2' is list<float>

// but as above you still have to be careful
let lcrash = addToList l b2 // crash
```